# HTTP Traffic Log for Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I've got an endpoint tied to a VM that is getting triggered unintentionally and I'm trying to figure out the source/client that is triggering this application.

What is the most efficient way to setup logging of HTTP traffic on an Azure VM? I don't need a lot of detail, mostly interested in the IP address of the client that is hitting this endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

For me i think you should have a firewall in-front of your VM ... which will detect the IP and maybe block it if you wish:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/tutorial-firewall-deploy-portal

Also you should use Azure Monitor or App insights to have an eye on what is happening on your VM:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-enable-portal

Hope that my answer helped you .... Dont hesitate to vote me up if it did ;)